# Mysql IF length > then update example

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to just say if a variable has a length at all update a table.  This is what i have but i'm not sure how to construct the query.

```
if(@CName length > 0) then 
  update mytableset IDName= @CName where mytable.ID = @CID end if;
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need for `IF/ELSE` logic -- you can use the variable in the `WHERE` clause. Use the `LENGTH()` string function and a boolean `AND`.

```
UPDATE mytable SET IDName = @CName WHERE LENGTH(@CName) > 0 AND mytable.ID = @CID
```

In order for the update to take place, both conditions must be true, but the `WHERE` clause conditions don't necessarily have to apply to table columns. They can be any arbitrary expression that evaluates to true or false.

Comment: Wait, the logic must be true, because the system will input '' and change the name if I dont use the length

Comment: There is a need, I have to say if the length is greater than x who cares make it 3

Comment: @Mike Look at the example above carefully ( I did just fix the `()`) The `LENGTH(@CName) > 3` (or whatever value) must be true for anything else to occur. It will work.  Test it as a `SELECT` statement to verify which rows would be modified.